# Polymorphism: Least cumbersome way to assign data fields?

Tags: java

I'm currently taking a Java course and have a question about polymorphism.

Given

```
public class A {

    private int a1;

    public A(){}
    public A(int a1) { this.a1 = a1;}

}

class B extends A {

    private int b1;

    public B() {}
    public B(int b1, int a1) {

    super(a1);
    this.b1 = b1;


    }
}

class C extends B {

    private int c1;

    public C(){}
    public C(int c1, int b1, int a1) {

    super(b1, a1);
    this.c1 = c1;

    }

}
```

What would be the best way to assign to fields a1, b1, and c1, all in one swoop? My first guess would be to make an instance of C and call its three-arg constructor.

But what happens when each class contains 10s or 100s of data fields? Wouldn't this approach mean calling constructors with huge numbers of arguments, like

C(arg1, arg2, ..., arg100), setting k of C's fields, then making a call to

B(arg1, arg2, ..., arg100-k), and so on,

all the way up to the top? Is there a better way to proceed?

Comment: There aren't many options, but if your constructor takes 100 parameters you're either a physicist, or something's probably wrong with your design.

Comment: If you have that many arguments, it's probably time to write some helper classes to group the related ones.  I cannot believe that you could have dozens or hundreds of fields without some relationships between them that let them be naturally grouped together.

Answer (score 4):

Having so many parameters is a definite code smell; in all probability you want to split the object up into smaller self-contained objects and/or or collections.

On the other hand, there is the Builder pattern, where you use a helper class to set all the parameters and it constructs the object for you, possibly sanity-checking that all required fields are set and there are no conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Not in this particular case because the fields in the parent classes are declared private.

If they were protected then you could set all 3 of them from the class C constructor. However this breaks encapsulation because if the constructor for B did something else after the value was assigned you'd have to duplicate that logic in C in order to not violate it's contract, and as you can imagine that gets very messy when you have more constructors or parent classes in the type tree.

Having multiple calls chained in the manner you proposed is the safest way at the cost of having to call all those constructors up the chain. I'd recommend profiling your code to see if this is actually a problem and not just a premature optimization.

Answer (score -1):

What you're suggesting would work if you set the class fields to public. Class C will have a1 and c1, but won't be able to access them due to them being private.

Comment: You should never make fields in your objects public, the proper scope for those variable should be protected or package private.